# Creating htaccess file - .us to .com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Looking for tips on writing an htaccess file for a .us to .com site transfer

Example: 
https://www.example.us/ to https://www.example.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.us [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.us [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This will redirect anything from `example.us` to `exmaple.com`. It will do this using a `301 redirect`.

This includes all directories.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** you test this.